# How to connect elipse or circle with line using css

Tags: html, css

I have a simple section in which I have two main ellipses or circle, I want to connect them using lines,

Here is how it should look

[image]

Here is jsfiddle I am working on [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6oz0jvqk/3/)

Here is HTML

```
<section id="main-content_bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-5" id="bubble-content">

            <div class="bubbles_projects">
                <span>366720</span>
                <p>number of projects</p>
            </div>
            <div class="bubbles_price">
                <span>$16</span>
                <p>trillion</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-custom" id="card-custom_bottom">
                <div id="card-body" class="card-body_bottom">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Do you want :</h5>

                    <ul clas='details-list'>
                        <li class="bottom-details">
                            Gain access to detailed information about these projects?

                        </li>
                        <li class="bottom-details">
                            Contact key decision makers?

                        </li>
                        <li class="bottom-details">
                            Generate sales leads?
                        </li>
                        <li class="bottom-details">
                            Gain visibility of project stakeholders and track their live activity

                        </li>
                        <li class="bottom-details">
                            Forecast market developments by country to plan your growth strategy

                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

What do I need to do to get what I want? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make easily like this

```css
.c1, .c2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
}

.c1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
}

.connect1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -80px;
  top: 130px;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.connect1::before, .connect1::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: orange;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.connect1::before {
  width: 200px;
  top: -20px;
  left: -180px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.connect1::after {
  width: 200px;
  right: -160px;
  top: 70px;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}

.c2 {
  left: 300px;
  top: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div class="connect1"></div>
</div>
<div class="c2"></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer what about the other lines outside those cicles?